# how can I replace %20 in url to hypen?

Tags: javascript, html, url

How can I achieve when I submit my search form if I fill up the input field box with space it shows me a result with %20 in url

for example:
Basketball coach

output:
basketball%20coach

I want this output:

basketball-coach

```html
<form action="/tag/" id="form-hockey_v1" name="form-hockey_v1" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div class="typeahead__container">
        <div class="typeahead__field">
            <div class="typeahead__query">
                <input class="js-typeahead-hockey_v1" id="search" name="q" placeholder="Search Services..." autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div id="typeahead_id" class="typeahead__button">
                <button class="searchsubmit" type="submit" onclick="window.location.href=this.form.action + this.form.q.value;">Search
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps use the `replace` method like this:

```
this.form.action + this.form.q.value.replace(/\s/gi,'-')
```

or, in context:

```
<form action="/tag/" id="form-hockey_v1" name="form-hockey_v1" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div class="typeahead__container">
        <div class="typeahead__field">
            <div class="typeahead__query">
                <input class="js-typeahead-hockey_v1" id="search" name="q" placeholder="Search Services..." autocomplete="off">
            </div>
            <div id="typeahead_id" class="typeahead__button">
                <button class="searchsubmit" type="submit" onclick="window.location.href=this.form.action + this.form.q.value.replace(/\s/gi,'-');">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

URLs can only be sent over the Internet using the [ASCII character-set](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp).

Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.

URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.
URLs cannot contain spaces. URL encoding normally replaces a space with a plus (+) sign or with %20.

**Note**: The JavaScript function encodes space as %20.

Comment: If you meant to replace space in your browser bar with special character your wanted!